# Errors creating a multithreaded named pipe server with Administrator only access on windows c++

Tags: multithreading, security, winapi, visual-c++, named-pipes

Im trying to create a multithreaded namedpipe server as outlined in the msdn sample here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server but Im trying to restrict the namedpipe to access by adminstrators group members only.

The example works correctly when no SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure is specified but when an SA is specified the first call is successful, but following calls to CreateNamedPipe fail as long as the first pipe is listening or communicating with a client. The create call fails, usually with ACCESS_DENIED, but sometimes with error 1305 The revision level is unknown. When the first pipe closes due to client disconnecting the following call will be successful for the next createnamedpipe call but will in turn fail once that pipe has a client.

I have tried multiple values for the grfInheritance field with no avail. This is my first adventure into explicitly specifying SECURITY so forgive me if I have missed something obvious. Note that in the Function that calls createnamedpipe I create a new SA structure with each create attempt but I have also tried creating one and sharing it outside the create loop.

Relevant code follows:

function that creates the pipe:

```
HRESULT DapiSettingsSvr::DapiSettingsListener()
{
    
    
    while(m_run)
    {   
        //find an unused control array member. If they are all used we have max connection so dont create a pipe.
        UINT connectId = 0;
        for (connectId; connectId < MAX_CONNECTIONS; connectId++)
        {
            if (m_controlArray[connectId].inuse == false)
                break;
        }

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
        HRESULT hr =  InitializeSecurity(&sa);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return hr;
        }

        if (connectId < MAX_CONNECTIONS)
        {
            HANDLE hpipe;
            

                hpipe = CreateNamedPipe(
                lpszPipename,               // pipe name 
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,         // read/write access 
                PIPE_TYPE_BYTE |            // byte bipe
                PIPE_READMODE_BYTE |        // read as bytes 
                PIPE_WAIT |                 // do not return until data is recieved
                PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS, // no remote connections               
                MAX_CONNECTIONS,            // max. instances  
                OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE,         // output buffer size 
                INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE,          // input buffer size 
                0,                          // client time-out 
                &sa);                       // default security attribute 

           // CleanUpSecurityResources();

            if (hpipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n", GetLastError());
                DapiSettingLogger(logbuffer);
            }
            else
            {
                m_controlArray[connectId].inuse = true;
                m_controlArray[connectId].pThis = this;
                m_controlArray[connectId].connectId = connectId;
                m_controlArray[connectId].pipehandle = hpipe;

                swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"\nPipe Server: Main thread awaiting client connection on %s\n", lpszPipename);
                DapiSettingLogger(logbuffer);

                // block until a client tries to connect.success is non zero. However a client can connect between the create call and ConnectNamedPipe call.
                //  In this case ConnectNamedPipe returns zero but GLE = ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED and a valid connection exists. Check for this case.
                fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hpipe, NULL) ? TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

                if (fConnected)
                {
                    // Create a thread for this client. 
                    m_controlArray[connectId].threadHandle = CreateThread(
                        NULL,              // no security attribute 
                        0,                 // default stack size 
                        WorkerInstance,    // thread proc
                        (LPVOID)&m_controlArray[connectId],    // thread parameter 
                        0,                 // not suspended 
                        &m_controlArray[connectId].threadId);      // returns thread ID 

                    if (m_controlArray[connectId].threadHandle == NULL)
                    {
                        swprintf_s(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"CreateThread failed, GLE=%d.\n", GetLastError());
                        DapiSettingLogger(logbuffer);
                        CloseHandle(m_controlArray[connectId].pipehandle);
                        ZeroMemory(&m_controlArray[connectId], sizeof(WORKER_INFO));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // The client could not connect, so close the pipe. 
                    CloseHandle(m_controlArray[connectId].pipehandle);
                    ZeroMemory(&m_controlArray[connectId], sizeof(WORKER_INFO));
                }                 
            } //else valid connection            
        }
        else 
        {
            DapiSettingLogger((LPWSTR) L"Max Connections reached\n");
        }       
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Function that creates the SA

```
HRESULT DapiSettingsSvr::InitializeSecurity(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* psa)
{
    HRESULT result = S_OK;
    DWORD res, error;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[1];
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    
    // Create a SID for the BUILTIN\Administrators group.
    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
        DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &m_pAdminSID))
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"AllocateAndInitializeSid Error %u\n", error);
        DapiSettingLogger(logbuffer);
        result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL;
    ea[0].grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
    ea[0].grfInheritance = SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT; //changing
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
    ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)m_pAdminSID;

    // Create a new ACL that contains the new ACE.
    res = SetEntriesInAcl(1, ea, NULL, &m_pACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res)
    {
        swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer),L"SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", res);
        DapiSettingLogger(logbuffer);
        result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(res);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize a descriptor Use localalloc as it allows memory moving without changing handle value 
    m_pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR,
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    if (NULL == m_pSD)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"LocalAlloc Error %u\n", error);
        result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(m_pSD,
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"InitializeSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n", error);
        result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(m_pSD,
        TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag   
        m_pACL,
        FALSE))   // not a default DACL 
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        swprintf(logbuffer, ARRAYSIZE(logbuffer), L"SetSecurityDescriptorDacl Error %u\n", error);
        result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

Cleanup:
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        CleanUpSecurityResources();
    }
    else
    {
        // Initialize a security attributes structure.
        psa->nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        psa->lpSecurityDescriptor = m_pSD;
        psa->bInheritHandle = TRUE;     /// NOTE I have toyed with this value also
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any input on what Im doing incorrectly would be greatly appriciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: your error code say that security descriptor is invalid. all code is not visible, but for instance - for what you call  `InitializeSecurity(&sa);` in loop, when it need be called only once ?

Comment: I have tried creating a new SA ( as above ) and passing the new SA to createnamedpipe as well as creating the SA one time outside of the loop and using the same SA in each call, with no difference. Not exactly sure what you mean by sa is invalid. As far as I can tell a valid sa is used in either case.

Comment: I just revised the problem description, I think it was unclear that the the first call creates a named pipe but additional calls to createnamedpipe fail as long as the first pipe is open and listening or open and reading \ writing.

Comment: no sense try do something without understanding. initialize sa in your case need only once, not in loop. *Not exactly sure what you mean by sa is invalid.* - about this say error `STATUS_UNKNOWN_REVISION`. may be you free `m_pSD` for instance.. not visible this. may be memory corrupted. check in debugger sa before second call

Comment: I have tried this already ( moving sa initialization outside the loop ), Same error when more than one connection is attempted.  `
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
 InitializeSecurity(&sa);

while(m_run)
    {   
        //find an unused control array member. If they are all used we have max connection so dont create a pipe.
        UINT connectId = 0;
        for (connectId; connectId < MAX_CONNECTIONS; connectId++)
        {
            if (m_controlArray[connectId].inuse == false)
                break;
        }'

Comment: moving sa initialization outside the loop - need not try but do. *Same error* - because the code same. again - check sa before second call - use `IsValidSecurityDescriptor` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Named Pipe Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-security-and-access-rights),

> In addition to the requested access rights, the DACL must allow the
> calling thread **FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE** access to the named pipe.

Comment: Thanks, Im a little confused about this particular permission. Do I add this to the ExplicitAccess structure that I create for the Admins group ( i.e. ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE ) or do I need to create another EA structure and add a second EA into the ACL that the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure points to? Thanks!

Comment: and ? `GENERIC_ALL` for files include `FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE`. error not in this. also this can not explain *sometimes with error 1305 The revision level is unknown*.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out. Im going to mark YangXiaoPo's answer as correct as this pointed me in the right direction but for clarification GENERIC_ALL already includes the right to FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE or at least thats what my testing indcates. So setting the EXPICIT_ACCESS structure field to ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE; does not resolve this issue.

The answer lies in the fact that I was running the PipeServer program from within visual studio ( debug ) and thus as a generic user. So the first time through the loop a pipe gets created and the SA with the local administrators group ACE is then applied to the pipe.
So we get a pipe created in the listening state. As soon as a client connects the working thread is created and then the the while(m_run) loop does another iteration and tries to create a new pipe instance. This attempt fails ( actually a looping fail ) because the security attribute with the administrators only ACL is now looked at and the program is not running as an administrator. As soon as the first client disconnects the working thread closes the pipe handle ( effectively destroying the pipe ) and then in the next iteration a  pipe is again created.
Running the program as Administrator ( or starting Visual studio as Admin and then debugging ) resolves the issue, though I think a fully correct solution would be to create a second ACE that specified Creator Owner in addition to Admin for the SA DACL.
Thanks!!